# Trilateration with more than 3 circles

Tags: geocoding, trilateration

I am trying to do the trilateration where I have exactly 4 beacon points and I considered each of them as the center of a circle. I have entirely followed the instruction provided  [in this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813615/trilateration-using-3-latitude-and-longitude-points-and-3-distances)  and also in  [in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration). I was just wondering, in case of 4 circles do I have to go through `4 Chosen 3` method? Or is there any alternative?

Any sort of help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can derive the formulas for 4 circles in the same manner that the Wikipedia article derived the formulas for 3 circles.

From the article, paraphrased: The solution is found by formulating the equations for the four sphere surfaces and then solving the four equations for the four unknowns, w, x, y, and z.

Actually, with 4 spheres, you can determine altitude, as well as latitude and longitude.

I'm afraid that the math is beyond me, but maybe someone else can help.