# Multilateration of GPS Coordinates

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, gps, coordinates

I have `N` GPS coordinates with `N` distances given to an unknown position which I wish to determine.

My first approach was to use just three points and trilateration, exactly as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813615/trilateration-using-3-latitude-and-longitude-points-and-3-distances]). This approach was already quite accurate (best error~5km), but I would like to improve this and increase the robustness.
Because the given distances are not very accurate to begin with, I thought about using multiple measurements and multilateration.
However, it turned out that this approach is by far less accurate (best error~100km) although I provide more than 3 points/distances (tested with up to 6) and now I am asking, if someone has an idea what I could have done wrong.

In short, my approach for multilateration is as follows:

1. Convert all coordinates into ECEF
2. Build a matrix as described in Eq.7 at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilateration)
3. Use SVD to find the minimizer
4. As the solution is only up to scale, I use a root-finding approach to determine a normalization so that the coordinates converted back into LLA result in a height of 0 (my initial assumption is that all coordinates are at zero height)
5. Convert back into LLA

LLA/ECEF conversion is double-checked and correct. Step 2 and 3 I've checked with euclidean coordinates (and exact distances) and appear correct. I came up with step 4 by myself, I have no clue if this is a good approach at all, so suggestions are welcome.

**+++UPDATE**

I've put together sample code in python to illustrate the problem
with some ground truth. Trilateration gets as close as 400m, while
Multilateration ranges at 10-130km here.
Because of length, I've put it at [ideone](http://ideone.com/umq2M)

Comment: The code at http://ideone.com/umq2M is not available?  Would you mind sharing it again?  I'm having some similar challenges!

Comment: @LeeArmstrong I need to check if I still find it on my old computer, but not sure if I have the 'broken' example somewhere. See my own answer below for some python code that eventually worked sufficiently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually, I figured it out myself - or at least improve the accuracy significantly.

The approach described at wikipedia (Eq.7) is apparently not very suited for this application, but in this case it is already a lot easier.

Considering Eq. 6 from wikipedia, we can simplify it a lot: `R_0` can be guessed as the earth radius, as the origin of ECEF coordinates lies in the center of earth. Therefore, there is no need to shift everything to make one Point the origin and we can use all `N` equations.

In python, with `P` an array of ECEF coordinates and `dists` the distances to these points, it all boils down to

```py
R = 6378137 # Earth radius in meters
A = []
for m in range(0,len(P)):
    x = P[m][0]
    y = P[m][1]
    z = P[m][2]
    Am = -2*x
    Bm = -2*y
    Cm = -2*z
    Dm = R*R + (pow(x,2)+pow(y,2)+pow(z,2)) - pow(dists[m],2)
    A += [[Am,Bm,Cm,Dm]]
# Solve using SVD
A = numpy.array(A)
(_,_,v) = numpy.linalg.svd(A)
# Get the minimizer
w = v[3,:]
w /= w[3] # Resulting position in ECEF
```

With this approach, what I described as *Step 4* is no longer necessary. In fact, it even makes the solution worse.

Now, accuracy ranges between 2km and 275m -- in most cases better than the "optimal" trilateration with an error of 464m.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Would you please be so kind to explain it to me? Is there any problem with this approach? Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

Some comments:

1) You have already checked some steps against exact answers. I suggest that you create toy problems with known amounts of random noise added to the observations. Since you know the right answer in this case you can see what happens with error propagation. If your method works well here but badly on real data you might want to think about horrid behaviour in real life, such as one or a few of the distances being seriously wrong.

2) I don't know why your solution is only up to scale, as the underlying data are properly scaled - if I went out there with ropes cut to length and tied them to the fixed points there would be no ambiguity. When you use SVD to solve the equations (7) are you doing something like www.cse.unr.edu/~bebis/MathMethods/SVD/lecture.pdf to get out a least squares solution? That should give you x, y, and z without ambiguity.

3) I'm not at all sure about how observational errors work through (7). I don't like all the divisions, for one thing. It might be worth writing down an equation for the sum of the squares of the differences between measured distances and computed distances given x,y,z for the unknown position, and then minimising this for x,y,z. The Wikipedia article discards this approach due to its cost, but it might give you a more accurate answer, and computing and comparing this answer might tell you something even if you can't use this method in practice.

Comment: Thanks, these are some good points I will verify further. Some remarks  so far: 1) I now have a "realistic" toy case without noise set up. In the best case, I get an error of 5-10km, however if I add another distance to a far away location, the error boosts to 150km. 2) I am working with homogeneous linear equation system, which is always up to scale (if `U` is a solution, `rU` is a solution as well, for any scalar `r`). I guess I should post some code to allow others to play around as well..

Comment: There is something fishy about eqn(7). It says in the article it is homogenous, and that would indeed introduce an ambiguity of scale, but it has non-zero constant coefficients Dm. In any case, you might be better off finding (x,y,z) to minimise the sum of squared differences between predicted and measured distances, as that is a maximum likelihood estimate assuming normal errors - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood for theoretical arguments that this may have decent properties.

Comment: eqn 7 is in fact not very suited in my case. I could modify it because I know that ECEF coordinates have the center of earth at origin (so their lengths is constant). Still, i'm getting an error of ~15km, but very robustly now.

Comment: It would be nice to do better than the 3-point case. I had a look at your code, but I'd have to set up Python and numpy to play with it (I'm mostly Java at home, with C++/Java at work). You could try minimising squared distance discrepancies easily if you have a bit of luck and don't care long a few tests take - try the Nelder-Mead simplex optimization algorithm - it only needs function values, not derivatives - see e.g. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html#scipy.optimize.fmin. Torczon simplex would be better, but can't find it for Python.

Comment: Yes, check my own answer to myself for a solution which should be in many cases better than 3-point. Regarding Nelder-Mead, that's also one of my favorites. But this problems screams for least squares / SVD, and apparently it now works quite nice. Though I guess there's still room for improvements.

Answer (score 0):

I followed @zerm's code shown above and it worked fairly well (yellow is calculated point from 3 towers). Results are shown in the Folium snippet. [Multilateration using linalg.SVD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIeqr.png)

However, when I followed the same algorithm with the changes that @mcdowella suggested (#2) using the Least Squares of an MxN System solution, results are much better. [Multilateration using Least Squares MxN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40D0S.png)

Here is the amended code:

```
A = []
b = []
for m in range(0,len(P)):
    x = P[m][0]
    y = P[m][1]
    z = P[m][2]
    Am = 2*x
    Bm = 2*y
    Cm = 2*z
    Dm = R*R + (pow(x,2)+pow(y,2)+pow(z,2)) - pow(dists[m],2)
    A += [[Am,Bm,Cm]]
    b += [[Dm]]
# Solve using Least Squares of an MxN System
# A*x = b --> x = (ATA)_inv.AT.b = A+.b
A = np.array(A)
b = np.array(b)
AT = A.T
ATA = np.matmul(AT,A)
ATA_inv = np.linalg.inv(ATA)
Aplus = np.matmul(ATA_inv,AT)
x = np.matmul(Aplus,b)
# convert back to lat/long from ECEF
# convert to degrees
lat = math.degrees(math.asin(x[2] / R))
lon = math.degrees(math.atan2(x[1],x[0]))
```

I'm still exploring other multilateration methods but this post really allowed me to understand the basics of N-points MLAT. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To improve [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8348145/2350083), one way to improve the SVD solution more is to account for the variation of the earth's radius by latitude; this particularly affects the altitude estimate, but it also has some knock-on effects on latitude and longitude. The "simple" solution would be to use the average value for `R`, which according to Wikipedia is 6371008.8 m rather than 6378137 m.

A more accurate estimate would be to adjust `R` for the latitude:

```
def EarthRadiusAtLatitude(lat):
    rlat = np.deg2rad(lat)

    a = np.float64(6378137.0)
    b = np.float64(6356752.3)

    rad = np.sqrt(((a*a*np.cos(rlat))**2 + (b*b*np.sin(rlat))**2) /
                  ((a*np.cos(rlat))**2 + (b*np.sin(rlat))**2))
    return rad
```

Then set `R` based on the latitude of one of the initial points. Or, if you have a large variation in latitude, you could compute the SVD based on an estimate of `R` and use the preliminary solution's latitude to solve using a closer estimate of `R`.

After making this adjustment, in my experiments with both constructed examples and "real world" data based on LTE eNodeB timing advance values, the SVD solution typically is within one second of latitude and longitude except in some degenerate cases, which is fairly comparable to a solution based on iterative optimization (i.e. minimizing the distance residuals).