# Multilateration Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

I'm trying to call upon the famous [multilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilateration) algorithm in order to pinpoint a radiation emission source given a set of arrival times for various detectors. I have the necessary data, but I'm still having trouble implementing this calculation; I am relatively new with Python.

I know that, if I were to do this by hand, I would use matrices and carry out elementary row operations in order to find my 3 unknowns `(x,y,z)`, but I'm not sure how to code this. Is there a way to have Python implement ERO, or is there a better way to carry out my computation?

Comment: You should probably take a look at numpy. Although I don't know the algorithm you are talking about, I'm pretty sure numpy can solve sets of equations, which is what you are after right?

Comment: That algorithm is so "famous" (at least among us), that you should have given a link...

Comment: Ah alright. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilateration
the algorithm I'm using is near the bottom, under 3-D solution.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, you could try:

- [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) if your interested in numerical solutions. As far as I remember, it could solve linear equations. Don't know how it deals with non-linear resolution.
- [SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) for symbolic math. It solves symbolically linear equations ... according to their main page.

The two above are "generic" math packages. I doubt you will find (easily) any dedicated (and maintained) library for your specific need. Their was already a question on that topic here: [Multilateration of GPS Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318113/multilateration-of-gps-coordinates)