# Wifi trilateration/triangulation in android

Tags: android, wifi

I'm working on indoor navigation application using the wifi trilateration ,

I have 3 access points I get the lat&lng for each

```
            //1 
    double Lat0 = 26.0475994;
    double Lng0 = 50.5101893;

            //2 

    double Lat1 = 26.0474428;
    double Lng1 = 50.5096745;

        //3
    double Lat2 = 26.0477956;
    double Lng2 = 50.5097067;
```

I need to convert each lat & lng to its x,y,z coordinates , can any one help me with this formula ? I saw a previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813615/trilateration-using-3-latitude-and-longitude-points-and-3-distances) but I'm not getting correct results

plus if I get x,y is ot possible to convert it to it's lat & lng ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

To convert from `latitude` and `longitude` to `x` and `y` coordinates you can use the following formula:

```
x = (radius of earth) * cos(latitude) * cos(longitude) //radians 
y = (radius of earth) * cos(latitude) * sin(longitude)
```

To convert back:

```
lat  = asin(y / (radius of earth)) // degrees
nong = atan(2 * x / y)             // degrees
```