# Coarse location from cell id (OpenCellId)

Tags: algorithm, math, location, trilateration

I have a device which reports me the GSM cell towers in sees:

- ID (Cell Id)
- MCC (Mobile country code)
- MNC (Mobile network code)
- LA (Location Area code)
- RxL (Received signal strength level) - *mosly useless since trasmitter power is unknown*
- Ta (Timing Advance) - distance to the cell tower (only for the active one)

Having the data from [OpenCellId](http://opencellid.org/), I can get the location of each cell tower. But how do I get the coarse location of the device itself?

- What circle radius to use, when TA is only known for a single tower, and RxL does not map to an absolute value?
- How to use N cells, where N=1,2,4?
- Which algorithms are available for this?
- Known pitfalls?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813615/trilateration-using-3-latitude-and-longitude-points-and-3-distances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation are two algorithms commonly used in this case.  How much information do you get beyond just tower ids?

Comment: Forgot the cell id, sorry :) Your links are correct, but precisely 3 circles are used, and my device can report less, or more. Also it's   not clear how to define the circle radius since the TA is only known for a single one. Signal power is usless as transmitter power is a variable